# Automatically Detect android device which has just entered in the range of my wifi router

Tags: android, push-notification, wifi, android-notifications, android-wifi

If any android device comes in the range of my wifi router I want to send the notification to that device automatically and get the reply when user click of OK button in the notification.

Is this possible to achive ? If yes, any help will be appreciated.

Thank you for investing your valuable time to read this post.

Answer (score 1):

Its Possible, By using Bounjour service  you can achieve this.

[**Bounjour service**](http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2013/01/start-bonjourcross-platform.html)

there are some limitation over there. You have to run your service in both a device(For Identifying device/sending data/receiving data).The devices should be in same network.